# Tuple as default value in function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, default-value

How can i put a tuple as default value in a function ?

These prototypes raise compile errors:

```
void f(std::tuple<int, int>=std::tuple<int, int>(1, 1));
void f(std::tuple<int, int>=std::make_tuple(1, 1));
void f(std::tuple<int, int>=(1, 1));
```

Comment: Put a space before the `=`.

Comment: `double` and `1.` are odd choices for `std::tuple<int, int>`.

Comment: Sorry, i have fixed that typo.

Comment: And you can't initialize it with `(1,1)`. That has to be `std::make_tuple(1,1)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you're missing is a space:

```
void f(std::tuple<int, int> =std::make_tuple(1, 1));
```

As-is, the `>=` is parsed as a single token.

Adding in a variable name would've also conveniently side-stepped the issue.

Comment: Is this how it is defined in standard? I would expect C+11 shouldn't have problems in parsing brackets

Comment: @texasbruce An exception was made for `>>`, but typically the rule is "max chomp"

Answer (score 0):

```
void f(std::tuple<int, int> t = std::make_tuple(1, 1));
```

or

```
void f(std::tuple<int, int> = std::make_tuple(1, 1));
```

or

```
void f(std::tuple<int, int> = std::tuple<int, int>(1, 1));
```

or

```
void f(std::tuple<int, int> = std::tuple<int, int>{1, 1});
```

Comment: Apparently, there are people (several > 1) here that down-vote with no particular reason. I'll take this as a compliment :P

Answer (score -1):

The whole thing is that you're missing the name :) You're forgetting to name your variable.

```
void f(std::tuple<int, int>x=std::make_tuple(1., 1.))
```

Should work

Check this [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) for more info.

> attr(optional) decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer

The "declarator" part is missing from your definition.

> Each declarator introduces a single variable or function into the
>   program. The most simple form of declarator is just the name you're
>   introducing - the declarator-id.